# attribute routing Visual studio C#

Tags: c#, attributes, http-post, asp.net-mvc-routing

The routing of My accountcontroller doesn't work and I don't see/understand what I'm doing wrong. I get & 404 with Postman. I tried just using 'app.UseMvc();' . I think I tried everything that doesn't work. Under need you see my code what is dealing with routing.

photo of my postman query --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpPsU.jpg

**Startup**

```
namespace GiveNTake
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes
                    .MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
                    .MapRoute(
                        name: "api",
                        template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}")

                ;
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallack",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();      
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace GiveNTake.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Register")]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterUserDTO registration)
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Register")]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterUserDTO registration)
        {
....
}
```

To:

```
        [Route("~/Account/Register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterUserDTO registration)
        {
.....
}
```

And add to your startup:

```
app.UseRouting();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that I'm working in .net core 2.2 . It isn't working but I'm gooing to check some tutorials to a newer version of .net. Tanks anyway.